# ¿Cómo ejecutar una acción desde touchesEnded en mi subclase de botón en SpriteKit?

Tags: xcode, swift4, spritekit

He creado una subclase de SKNode para crear mis propios botones en mi escena. He conseguido que los botones se muestren correctamente, pero no que funcionen. He creado un método en la clase del botón que toma la acción que quiero añadir al botón. Pero no sé cómo pasar dicha acción al sobrescribir la función touchesEnded(). He buscado y probado varias cosas pero nada funciona. Este es mi código:

```
var actionTouchUpInside: Selector?
var actionTouchUp: Selector?
var actionTouchDown: Selector?
weak var targetTouchUpInside: AnyObject?
weak var targetTouchUp: AnyObject?
weak var targetTouchDown: AnyObject?


func setButtonAction(target: AnyObject, triggerEvent event:SKButtonActionType, action:Selector) {

    switch (event) {
    case .TouchUpInside:
        targetTouchUpInside = target
        actionTouchUpInside = action
    case .TouchDown:
        targetTouchDown = target
        actionTouchDown = action
    case .TouchUp:
        targetTouchUp = target
        actionTouchUp = action
    }
}
override public func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.location(in: parent!)
        if self.contains(location) {
            // Aquí debería haber algo para ejecutar la acción
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solución:**

Era problema de pasar una función de obj-c (creada con `@objc func`) en vez de una función normal. En el ejemplo de código provisto en la pregunta, donde dice:

// Aquí debería haber algo para ejecutar la acción

Se debe, en efecto, escribir el código a ejecutar.

Si se quiere utilizar la función `setButtonAction(target: , event: , action: )` hay que cambiar lo siguiente:

```
var actionTouchUpInside: (() -> Void)?
var actionTouchUp: (() -> Void)?
var actionTouchDown: (() -> Void)?
weak var targetTouchUpInside: AnyObject?
weak var targetTouchUp: AnyObject?
weak var targetTouchDown: AnyObject?


func setButtonAction(target: AnyObject, triggerEvent event:SKButtonActionType, action: @escaping () -> Void) {

    switch (event) {
    case .TouchUpInside:
        targetTouchUpInside = target
        actionTouchUpInside = action
    case .TouchDown:
        targetTouchDown = target
        actionTouchDown = action
    case .TouchUp:
        targetTouchUp = target
        actionTouchUp = action
    }
}
override public func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let location = touch.location(in: parent!)
        if self.contains(location) {
            // Aquí debería haber algo para ejecutar la acción
        }
    }
}
```

Teniendo en cuenta que la función que le pasamos a `setButtonAction()` no acepta parámetros y no devuelve ningún valor. de lo contrario, bastará con cambiar `() -> Void` para adecuar el código a los tipos de los parámetros de entrada y salida de la función que vayamos a pasarle.